# Command timesout [osd1][INFO ] Running command: sudo /usr/sbin/ceph-volume

Tags: ceph

I'm having issues running ceph-deploy or creating manually osd

My environment is virtual machines on openstack which each have a virtual volume attached. Ubuntu 16.04

The command hangs at the below command:

```
    ubuntu@mr-jb:~/cluster$ ceph-deploy osd create --data /dev/sdb osd1 --debug
[ceph_deploy.conf][DEBUG ] found configuration file at: /home/ubuntu/.cephdeploy.conf
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ] Invoked (2.0.1): /usr/local/bin/ceph-deploy osd create --data /dev/sdb osd1 --debug
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ] ceph-deploy options:
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  verbose                       : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  bluestore                     : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  cd_conf                       : <ceph_deploy.conf.cephdeploy.Conf instance at 0x7fccd3ea9638>
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  cluster                       : ceph
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  fs_type                       : xfs
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  block_wal                     : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  default_release               : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  username                      : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  journal                       : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  subcommand                    : create
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  host                          : osd1
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  filestore                     : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  func                          : <function osd at 0x7fccd40fe6e0>
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  ceph_conf                     : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  zap_disk                      : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  data                          : /dev/sdb
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  block_db                      : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  dmcrypt                       : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  overwrite_conf                : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  dmcrypt_key_dir               : /etc/ceph/dmcrypt-keys
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  quiet                         : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  debug                         : True
[ceph_deploy.osd][DEBUG ] Creating OSD on cluster ceph with data device /dev/sdb
[osd1][DEBUG ] connection detected need for sudo
sudo: unable to resolve host mr-osd-1
[osd1][DEBUG ] connected to host: osd1
[osd1][DEBUG ] detect platform information from remote host
[osd1][DEBUG ] detect machine type
[osd1][DEBUG ] find the location of an executable
[ceph_deploy.osd][INFO  ] Distro info: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
[ceph_deploy.osd][DEBUG ] Deploying osd to osd1
[osd1][DEBUG ] write cluster configuration to /etc/ceph/{cluster}.conf
[osd1][DEBUG ] find the location of an executable
[osd1][INFO  ] Running command: sudo /usr/sbin/ceph-volume --cluster ceph lvm create --bluestore --data /dev/sdb
[osd1][WARNIN] No data was received after 300 seconds, disconnecting...
[osd1][INFO  ] checking OSD status...
[osd1][DEBUG ] find the location of an executable
[osd1][INFO  ] Running command: sudo /usr/bin/ceph --cluster=ceph osd stat --format=json
[osd1][WARNIN] No data was received after 300 seconds, disconnecting...
[ceph_deploy.osd][DEBUG ] Host osd1 is now ready for osd use.
ubuntu@mr-jb:~/cluster$

Output of fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 30 GiB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Even though it states that it is ready to use, it is not appearing in ceph -s

 cluster:
    id:     188ba861-a425-41df-a406-bf3008a12f2d
    health: HEALTH_OK

  services:
    mon: 1 daemons, quorum mr-mon-1
    mgr: mr-mon-1(active)
    osd: 0 osds: 0 up, 0 in

  data:
    pools:   0 pools, 0 pgs
    objects: 0  objects, 0 B
    usage:   0 B used, 0 B / 0 B avail
    pgs:

Answer (score 1):

I feel like an idiot.

Long story short,
Openstack security groups were blocking the ports for the OSD to talk to the MON.